# how to enable innodb in Server version: 10.2.30-MariaDB

Tags: mysql, magento, mariadb, cpanel, innodb

Magento was running okay till now but today its not working.

After checking and researching, i got this, that the innoDB is not supported.

Server version: 10.2.30-MariaDB

This MySQL server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.

[show engines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYlOw.jpg)

Comment: Is skip-innodb set explicitly in the my.cnf options file? That's the only scenario I can think of where InnoDb would be disabled, but the mysqld server process would still be able to successfully start up ...

Comment: my.cnf doesnot have skip-innodb.. actually now I came to know that the InnoDB got corrupted. :(

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: nothing was there which can help.
Later finding got that its was the issue related to CRON JOBs. It was full.